# Swagger UI don't display enum values in models

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I'm facing a little problem using Swagger UI and I'm not sure yet wheter is it a bug or not...

I've described my API using Swagger Editor and I have a method that contains an enum parameter.

Now, the problem: in the Swagger-UI documentation generated, in the 'model' tab, I have an empty definition of the 'messageType' object :(  I want to display the allowed values (BRAND, VISITOR, COMMENT and RESPONSE)

A code snippet to reproduce:

```
swagger: '2.0'
info:
  version: 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
  title: foo
  description: foo
host: dev.fr
basePath: /base
schemes:
  - http
  - https
consumes:
  - application/json
produces:
  - application/json

paths:
  /social/message:
    post:
      operationId: create
      responses:
        '201':
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/message'
        'default':
          description: Default error response

definitions:
  message:
    required:
      - title
      - messageType
    properties:
      title:
        type: string
      messageType:
        $ref: '#/definitions/messageType'

  messageType:
    enum:
      - COMMENT
      - RESPONSE
```

[image: screen capture]

Any idea ? I am doing it wrong ? Is it a bug ?
Many thanks :)

Comment: Your `messageType` doesn't declare it's `type`.  `enum` is not a valid type in JSON schema.  Consider adding `type: string` as a sibling to the enum.

Comment: You're ritght ! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fehguy is right, problem solved by adding "type: string" on my object :)